# If current is measured in Coulombs per second, can there be electrical "acceleration"? Coulombs per second squared?

Tags: kinematics, electric-current, charge, acceleration

I know I'm making a naïve parallel between current and speed, but why is it naïve? Why doesn't the concept apply?

Comment: Yes. Inductors, for example, have a potential difference proportional to this "acceleration".

Comment: $I=\dot{Q}$, so $\dot{I} = \ddot{Q}$. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, coulomb per second squared is just the variation of the current, $\frac{dI}{dt}$. It's not uncommon to see this quantity appear when you want to determine an electromotive force for instance.

Comment: Consider spelling out acronyms the first time even if it might be well known, also Coulomb per square meter is a area charge density not a charge "acceleration." I am guessing you meant square second and not meter.